# How to make lightbulbs filament stronger?

Tags: high-power

If I make the tungsten filament in a lightbulbs thicker could it then handle high electricity flowing through it without burning up so fast. Also could making it thick, allow it to handle being cut off and on very rapidly, a few thousands times for hours on end and still not metal?
This is for a special fun project I'm working on f.y.I and I need to know if I can make the tungsten filament handle more power at a rapid speed for a very long time.

Comment: How do you plan to change the filament in the bulb?

Comment: Not change the filament in a lightbulb, but in a sense create my own.

Comment: Since it has less resistance will that increase 5the heat that's coming from the filament? Sorry I'm still in the basics.

Comment: tungsten filaments are wound to < 2% thickness variation because the weakest link breaks it.. Rugged bulbs are less efficient and using less than rated power makes them slower.  Considering stress factor on cold filaments is 10x, long time is not possible.

Comment: You might want to study "rough service" bulbs. They're designed for high-vibration environments, but some of the design features might also help with your application.